# Space between links in a div element

Tags: css, html

I am new to using div tags, and I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure this problem out. I have searched for hours, and I can't seem to find a good solution that works.

I am currently making a horizontal menu in one div element.
I cannot use multiple div elements nested in one because that will cause the elements to wrap when I resize the browser.
I cannot use float:left because that will also cause the elements to wrap when I resize the browser.

I have tested the above and multiple other snippets of code, but I cannot remove the space between links in the menu. Here is my code.

```
<div style=" display:inline-block; width:100%; padding: 0.1em 0.6em; border-collapse:collapse; max-height:100px; margin-top:-1px; margin-left:30%; overflow-y:hidden;">

<img src="logo.png" />
<img src="cornerthing4.png" /><a href="index.php"><img src="homebtn.png"></a><a href="index.php"><img src="faqbtn.png"></a><img src="cornerthing3.png">



</div>
```

I am using the style tag because I am trying to design the page right now, I will be moving the css code over to a css file when I am finished.

When the `<a href>` tag is removed, the images are side by side where I want them to be. As soon as I put that tag on they gain a 20 pixel space in between.

Any insight as to why this occurs and how to correct it would be great.

EDIT: the code works in jfiddle, however, it does not work on my website. Here is a link to the site: http://matxor.net/header.php

Comment: When you give `inline-block` display, and if you give spaces between them, it is considered as a **white-space**. Can you show us a fiddle?

Comment: And yeah, when I tried, all the five images are without any spaces. http://jsfiddle.net/FXuxr/

Comment: Have you tried adding a style="padding:0px" to the IMG tag?

Comment: do you have any css styles on the <a> tag? also you could try `a, img{margin: 0; padding: 0;}` that will make sure there is no margin or padding on either the <img> tag or the <a> tag.

Comment: p.s. it helps if you post a jsfiddle... then people can see what's going on better.

Comment: If it works in JSFiddle and not in real life, it's usually due to the fact that JSFiddle applies a global reset to strip out all browser-specific styling. Try applying a CSS reset to your production code and then apply your styles to the new (clean) environment.

Comment: Btw, dunno if you're using it, but this is a situation where tools like firebug (for Firefox) and inspect element (for Chrome) are VERY useful-- once you posted the link, we could tell in an instant the styles you applied and where they came from. 2 people beat me to answering, though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **a** style has a margin. This margin is not present in the markup you pasted here. Is that what you're trying to get rid of?

```
a:link {
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: #0A58A5;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Ah! its always the small things isn't it? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Take the `margin-left:30px` rule off `<a>` tags and it will look how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am currently making a horizontal menu in one div element. I cannot use multiple div elements nested in one because that will cause the elements to wrap when I resize the browser. I cannot use float:left because that will also cause the elements to wrap when I resize the browser.

Sure you can!

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/fY48A/

In this example, the elements won't wrap on themselves and the container div is still `100%` of the width.

Comment: I didn't down vote you, I wish I could up vote you because your response was really helpful but I lack the required reputation.
Thanks!

Comment: @MatXOR I wasn't blaming you, I don't you think have that ability until 10 rep (you should have it now). I don't understand the downvote though (whoever did it) because I did address a part of the question, not a wrong answer.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted either, but if I had to guess.. I'd guess someone didn't like the scrolling menu.